# will i lose my work if i svn update my working copy first?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I cannot commit to "SVN".

We are storing our project in this SVN remote location.Currently 2 people are working in this project.For example, my friend commit his project 2 days ago and I did not update his work in my local working copy.Now I have worked on my own part. If I try to commit it says I have to update my working copy first.

If I do that, will I lose my work that I did and will be restored to whatever my friend so far done in the last commit?

Comment: Take backup and try it yourself.

Comment: You will never lose your work - at most you will get notified that there is a conflict between your local changes and the changes your friend committed.

Comment: thxx rathna and Filburt i updated my working copy then i commit now i have few files that has conflicts ...how can i fix this?

Comment: Since you are using tortoisesvn, you can open the svn context menu on your conflicted file and open `Diff` to step through all conflicts and decide to use your friends changes or yours or both. Maybe consider watching a tutorial because it would a bit long winded to explain merging conflicts here.

Comment: thx Filburt, i was not very clear about using svn .. now after facing the conflicts issue and solving it.. i think it's kinda cool. that it merges both work and checks by line number to see the changes . well that's the main use of svn right.. similar to git hub.

Comment: Many folks prefer git or mercurial over svn for exact the reason you experienced. Joel has a nice [Subversion Re-education](http://hginit.com/00.html).